# Haproxy Rewrite forward

Tags: haproxy

I am new with HaProxy. Using 1.4.27

I will make it easy.

I have a proxy with some services which have a specific backend which makes the forward to the server. 
For instance:

- haproxy-server/service1...-> is forwarded to server-1:8080/service1
- haproxy-server/service2...-> is forwarded to server-2:8080/service2

I don't have any problem with this.

However, I have the issue because I also want a default backend which makes a forward to another server and rewrite the url.

For instance:

- haproxy-server/ -> is forwarded and rewrite to server-N:8080/added-path
- haproxy-server/whatever -> is forwarded and rewrite to server-N:8080/added-path/whatever

I have tried to combine reqrep(to reqerite the url) and server(to forward), but doesn't work. Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `default_backend` directive.

```
frontend blah_fe
    ...
    default_backend serverNs_be
```

Check the HAProxy manual out.

Comment: Thank you. I made a work around which is an specific case of my app. So it's not worthy to share it in here.

But thank you very much